# real time series, differences in numpy ifft v. irfft

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I want to generate a random time series with a prescribed spectral shape.  To do this I will draw random complex Fourier coefficients with from the appropriate spectral distribution then transform the frequency to the time domain.

To generate a real time series, the Fourier spectrum must have real DC and Nyquist coefficients and have symmetric negative frequencies.

When I do this, I get different behavior from numpy's `ifft` versus its `irfft`.

As an example, here's a 32 sample white spectrum:

```
import numpy as np

Nsamp = 2**5
Nfreq = (Nsamp-1)//2 # num pos freq bins not including DC or Nyquist

DC = 0.
f_pos = np.random.randn(Nfreq) + 1j*np.random.randn(Nfreq)
Nyquist = np.random.randn() # this is real
f_neg = f_pos[::-1] # mirror pos freqs

f_tot = np.hstack((DC, f_pos, Nyquist, f_neg))
f_rep = np.hstack((DC, f_pos, Nyquist))

t1 = np.fft.ifft(f_tot)
t2 = np.fft.irfft(f_rep)

print(t1)
print(t2)
```

I would expect both `t1` to be real and `t1` and `t2` to agree (within machine precision).  Neither is true.

Am I using the `ifft` correctly?  Looking at the frequencies output by `np.fft.fftfreq(Nsamp)`, makes me think I'm building `f_tot` correctly for input.

`irfft` is the correct result, so I'll use that... but I'd like to know how use `ifft` for the future.

---

from the [`numpy.fft` docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/routines.fft.html):

> `A[0]` contains the zero-frequency term (the sum of the signal), which is always purely real for real inputs. Then `A[1:n/2]` contains the positive-frequency terms, and `A[n/2+1:]` contains the negative-frequency terms, in order of decreasingly negative frequency. For an even number of input points, `A[n/2]` represents both positive and negative Nyquist frequency, and is also purely real for real input.

Comment: for starters, the fourier transform of a real-valued sequence is *conjugate* symmetric with respect to DC

Comment: well, that's the issue... how did I forget that